# How to set the tooltip delay for one component only in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

The [TooltipManager](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=tooltips_4.html) allows to set `showDelay`, `hideDelay` and `scrubDelay` properties. However, these are statics, so I assume they are global for all components in my application. I would like to change those values for 1 component only. How can this be done?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you can easily create a custom tooltip with PopUpAnchor, which gives you full control over its appearance and behaviour. If there's no easy fix for your problem, this might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It should work to register a `ToolTipEvent.TOOL_TIP_START` event on the component which sets `ToolTipManager.showDelay` to the preferred value, and a `ToolTipEvent.TOOL_TIP_HIDE` event which resets `showDelay`.